# How to fsck a partition that is part of a software Raid that again is part of a LVM volume group?

Tags: linux, lvm, software-raid, fsck

The faulty partition is /dev/sdb3.

from /proc/mdstat:

```
md2 : active raid1 sda3[2]
      2896184639 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
```

says /etc/fstab:

```
# /dev/md/2 belongs to LVM volume group 'vg0'
/dev/vg0/backups  /backups  ext4  defaults 0 0
/dev/vg0/root  /  ext4  defaults 0 0
```

says pvs:

```
PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize PFree 
/dev/md2   vg0  lvm2 a--  2.70t 50.00g
```

says lvs:

```
LV      VG   Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
backups vg0  -wi-ao-- 974.00g                                           
root    vg0  -wi-ao--   1.70t
```

Is it possible to fsck.ext4 (or badblock) the /dev/sdb3, **as long as the machine is running**? (W/out getting a "Device or resource busy" due to the LVM).

Comment: The partitions are on the logical volumes, not the disk partition. Thus the *partition* cannot be corrupt in a filesystem sense since the actual partition contains no filesystems.

Comment: you need to do fsck on the lvm logical volume not in your disk partition.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So it's not possible to do this on the running server as the check has to be on the lvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't even try to do fsck on a specific partition, because you're using software RAID and LV on top of it. So the filesystem is on other/"higher" level.

But you could use badblocks on a specific partition if it's not used by OS (/dev/sdb3 in this case). Then you could (and you should) re-add your partition to the RAID, if the device state is OK, by using option "--re-add".